# How to store in Angular fuction return value into variable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I wanted to store the return value of an function into an variable. I tried this simple example.

```
drawChart(){
     var data = this.prepareData();
}

prepareData() {
    return 1;
}
```

But I got the error message:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prepareData')

Thank you for every help.

Comment: Please provide more context. Your code looks good. Could you share the whole class?

Comment: looks like your not in a object instance. just remove this and it should work

Comment: How is the `drawChart()` called? Based on the error message, most probably it's used as a callback.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `drawChart()` method in `ngOnInit()`.

So this method gets call and you can get the return value from the `prepareData()` method

Here I'm attaching stackblitz url for your ref : [stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m89rr5?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Hope that solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place drawChart() and prepareData() outside the ngInit(), constructor() and inside the component.

eg :

```
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

   ngOnInit() {
     this.drawChart();
   }

   drawChart(){
       var data = this.prepareData();
    }

  prepareData() {
     return 1;
  }
 }
```

"this" keyword will point to the variables and functions inside the class, If you have declare these function inside a function, that won't work.